# bash: grepping for double quotes is failing

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep stdin for a string that looks like this:

```
"\t", 7
```

The number '7' is a variable, so I want to do something like this:

```
mumble | grep "\"\\t\", $number"
```

The grep isn't returning anything. I tried to decompose this in to its simplest terms:

```
$ echo '"\t"'
"\t"
```

... as expected.

```
$ echo "\"\\t\""
"\t"
```

This renders the string that I want when interpolated in double quotes. But...

```
$ echo '"\t"' | grep "\"\\t\""
```

doesn't return anything.

Ok, let's turn on set -x to see what bash thinks is going on...

```
$ echo '"\t"' | grep "\"\\t\""
+ grep '"\t"'
+ echo '"\t"'
```

... so I'm grepping for exactly what's being echoed... and single quotes aren't special characters in basic regex, so why isn't grep matching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ' asdfdf "\t",7 asdfadsf' | grep '"\\t",7'
```

Answer (score 1):

DoH!

'\' is a special character in regex...

```
$ echo -n '"\t"' | grep "\"\\\\t\""
+ grep '"\\t"'
+ echo -n '"\t"'
"\t"
```

matches.